# Grails 5.1 multi plugin dependency issue

Tags: grails, groovy, plugins, dependencies, grails-5

**Expected Behavior**

Main app: A (Depends on B)

Plugin: B (Depends on C)

Plugin: C

Suppose, if we have some services or files or dependencies in Plugin C, then we can easily access any file or dependency file of **Plugin C from Main App A** (Reason: Main App depends on plugin B and plugin B depends on plugin C).

This is working fine for Grails 3.1.6 and Grails 3.3. So, must be working for Grails 5.1.7 too.

**Actual Behaviour**
We are working on a Grails upgrade from 3.1.6 to 5.1.7. In Grails 3.1.6, we are using multiple plugins and interdependent plugins and dependencies. But following the same process is not working for Grails 5.1.7.

For Grails 5.1.7, we are not able to access the file of **Plugin C from Main App A** implementing a similar approach as of Grails 3.1.6.

Environment Information

- macOS Monterey : openjdk zulu version "1.8.0_332-b09"
- Windows 10 : openjdk version "1.8.0_181"

**Example Application:** https://github.com/sghatuwa/grails3vsgrails5

**Issue Version:** 5.1.7

Answer (score 0):

Create your project as a multi project Gradle build as per the [Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html)

I made a few changes to your [5.1.7](https://github.com/leadtrip/grails3vsgrails5/tree/main/grails517) project which is now building.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Mike. But still, my problem is not solved yet.
You had added **implementation project(":IMSDomainPlugin")** in IMS build.gradle. But, IMSDomainPlugin can only used under IMSPlugin for my case. 

That means we cannot use IMSDomainPlugin under IMS (main plugin).

In my sample project as mentioned in question, IMSPlugin is added as dependency from **apply from: "gradle/dev.gradle"** (line 24 of build.gradle of IMS) and IMSDomainPlugin  is added under IMSPlugin from line 20 of build. gradle of IMSPlugin.

Please suggest.